# How to make a dictionary from a given txt file?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, findall

Task: given a txt file with **adjective \t synonym, synonym, synonym, etc.** in a line, several lines are given. I need to create a dictionary, where adjective will be a key and synonyms - a value. My code:

```
#necessary for command line + regex
import sys 
import re

#open file for reading
filename = sys.argv[1]
infile = open(filename, "r")

#a
#create a dictionary, where an adjective in a line is a key
#and synonyms are the value

dictionary = {}
#for each line in infile
for line in infile:
    
    #creating a list with keys, a key is everything before the tab
    adjectives = re.findall(r"w+\t$", line)
    print(adjectives)
    
    #creating a list of values, a value is everything after the tab
    synonyms = re.findall(r"^\tw+\n$", line)
    print(synonyms)
    
    #combining both lists into a dictionary, where adj are keys, synonyms - values
    dictionary = dict(zip(adjectives, synonyms))
    print(dictionary)

#close the file
infile.close()
```

The output shows me the empty brackets... Could someone help to fix?

Comment: What about print(adjectives) and print(synonyms) calls - do you see some output?

Comment: In the regular expressions "w" must be escaped with backslash, too.

Comment: You're redefining your dictionary every time from scratch instead of adding a new key every time.

Comment: `dictionary[adjectives] = synonyms`

Comment: Why are you using `findall()` to get the adjective? There's only one adjective on each line,right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regular expressions, use `split()` to split strings using delimiters. First split it using `\t` to separate the adjective from the synonyms, then split the synonyms into a list using `,`.

Then you need to add a new key in the dictionary, not replace the entire dictionary.

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip() # remove newline
    adjective, synonyms = line.split("\t")
    synonyms = synonyms.split(",")
    dictionary[adjective] = synonyms

print(dictionary)
```